# How to get VCAP_SERVICES environment variables WITHOUT binding to an application?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Frequently, I'm create standalone services in Bluemix.  For example, Analytics for Apache Hadoop, Cloudant and DashDB.

I don't need an application to work with these services, but it seems I have to bind to an application just to get access to the VCAP_SERVICES environment variables with urls, usernames, passwords, etc.

**Question**: How to get VCAP_SERVICES environment variables WITHOUT binding to an application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For many services, you will have to bind them to an app in order to get the VCAP_SERVICES credentials.

There is a service key capability which some services are starting to adopt which allows you to create and access credentials without binding to an app.  Using the `cf` command line tool, the commands below are available to use if a service supports them:

```
SERVICES:
   create-service-key, csk                       Create key for a service instance
   service-keys, sk                              List keys for a service instance
   service-key                                   Show service key info
   delete-service-key, dsk                       Delete a service key
```

The CloudFoundry docs at https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/service-keys.html provide more detail.

In the Bluemix UI, you would see a 'Service Credentials' option in the panel when viewing a service dashboard when a service supports this capability.  Selecting this option allows you to see credentials that have been created as well as an "Add Credentials" button to create new ones.